# What does Terminal.app store in iCloud?

Tags: terminal, icloud

I just noticed this. What does Terminal.app store in iCloud?
[image]

Comment: Perhaps the command history. But this is only a guess.

Comment: Command history gets stored in the .history file.

Comment: That's interesting, I'm updated to latest OS and don't have Terminal.app in that list.

Comment: It's quite odd, I don't see Terminal.app in my iCloud preferences. Maybe it's an app, using Terminal.app as an interface to store files in iCloud.

Comment: Terminal doesn't explicitly store anything in iCloud. Please consider filing a bug report with Apple about it appearing in the list: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal.app stores your preference options on iCloud (basically things like the font and background colours)

Specifically its a copy of 
preference file `"com.Apple.Terminal.plist"` in `Users/<yourusername>/Library/Preferences`

Comment: I voted this up, but I'm not so sure this synchronizes. In terminal if I run `brctl status | grep -i terminal` I see no containers and I have changed the terminal preferences to open non-white colored windows. I do have Terminal listed in the preference pane, but one Mac has 128 lines in the plist and the other has 658 lines as measured by `defaults read com.Apple.Terminal.plist|wc -l` - Can you elaborate on how these preferences are syncing? I am seeing zero items in common between two Macs that have iCloud Drive on and the preferences are clearly not the same on both Macs.

Comment: My preferences file isn’t stored in iCloud. Terminal does not appear in the list of apps that save documents to iCloud, and my `~/Library/Mobile Documents` folder does not show Terminal either.